# How to create a "copy" of SQL Server transaction log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want a copy of SQL Server transaction log file for "raw" analysis. What is the **safest** way to get a copy of that file without shutting down the database and disturbing the existing log/backups/backup schedules and just about everything.

FYI, Its a SQL Server 2000 database server and I can see the log file (its about 4GB in size) and I cannot copy it as is; I get the "access denied" error when copying from explorer or command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not analyse the log file backups instead of the log file itself?  If you must have a copy of the log file itself, restoring a backup of the database and all transaction logs will give you a replica of the transaction log file in a different database.

Comment: I think log analyzers cost $s :(

Comment: You're using SQL 2000 so yo can use the FRE RedGate tool: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_log_rescue/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a copy of a transaction log file, Although, you can create the backup of your database and restore it in another location with another name and then you can detach it.